# Replacement class for MultiActionController which is deprecated in 4.3.3

Tags: java, spring

While fixing all the deprecated api's when upgrading to **Spring 4.3.3**, I'm facing an issue with the `MultiActionController` class which is used in multiple locations.

Are there any **alternative** classes in spring which have the same functionality as `MultiActionController`?

As per the spring [docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.1.RELEASE/deprecated-list.html):

> as of 4.3, in favor of annotation-driven handler methods ,we need to
>   follow annotation .

Are annotations the only solution or are there any other classes or workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, annotations are the only way now, unless you're willing to use the deprecated `MultiActionController` class.

In the javadoc for the `MultiActionController` class, they state that it's deprecated in favor of annotations, so logically there should be an annotation to replace (or at least mimic) the majority on methods within the class. They don't list any other alternatives or workarounds so I doubt there are any. The methods don't specify anything either.

Here is the [Spring 4.3.3 framework reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf) which could aid you in tracking down the annotations you're looking for. Section 30.6 -  Annotation-driven listener endpoints would be a good place to start.

Here is a page on [Migrating to spring framework 4.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-to-Spring-Framework-4.x), and finally, a page on [Converting a Spring Controller into a @Controller](https://dzone.com/articles/converting-spring-controller). These links should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Luke for the answer .We will follow annotations only.But it's really pathetic to do many changes in our code  for a warning.It requires lot of effort for testing that's why I posted for any other suggestions.