# Is MultiActionController not support in Spring framework 5.2.8.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-framework-beans

I added spring framework 5.2.8.RELEASE in dependency. After jar loaded when I'm trying to access **MultiActionController**.class observred that **org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction** this package is missing. Is there this package deprecated in this version?

[image]

Comment: Its deprecated since  4.3. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41167830/replacement-class-for-multiactioncontroller-which-is-deprecated-in-4-3-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`MultiActionController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/MultiActionController.html) was marked deprecated in 4.3

> Deprecated as of 4.3, in favor of annotation-driven handler methods

and was removed in 5.x

Thus you should convert it to an [annotated controller](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-controller).

Comment: This does not fix the OPs issue, which is also my issue.  I have a controller class that inherits from MultiActionController; it has had an @Controller annotation since forever.  Simply removing the "extends MultiActionController" will not solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, simply removing the extends will not work. But this is not what I proposed.  I said "convert it", which means you have to modify it using annoations so that the original behavior is maintained. So every action method in the MultiActionController must be annotated too. E.g. a `RequestMapping` or `GetMaping`.

Comment: It's not just action methods that need to be annotated.  There are methods in MAC that need to be overridden in order to supply the same or equivalent behavior.  The MAC used to supply a ServletContext and an ApplicationContext, as well as methods such as applyCacheSeconds().  I had to recreate all of those things and also implement ServletContextAware and ApplicationContextAware.  It may still not be enough (I'll find out soon enough once I start the app and run it through its paces).  In my case, I'm converting an app using Spring 3.x and JDK 1.8 to Spring 6.x and JDK 17: lots of work!

Comment: Maybe you can post your answer when you finished the migration.